# Converting PHP escape codes

Tags: php, escaping, simplexml

I'm using simplexml to read the contents of an utf-8 XML source.

The source contains escaped characters like the French E...

```
15 THE AVENUE EXAMPLE CL&#201;MENCEAU
```

And I'm saving it to a variable like this:

```
$shipping_street1 = (string) $order->{'shipping-address'}->address1;
```

That works fine but the French E gets mangled to:

```
15 THE AVENUE EXAMPLE CLÃ‰MENCEAU
```

And I need to write the values to a plain old text file. I though about just replacing the text with a plain E but thought there must be a better solution. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: A plain old text file with what character encoding?

Comment: Can you clarify: does the French E get mangled when you save it to the text file, or echo it out for debugging?

Comment: @Craig Sefton It's getting mangled in the file and during echo.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the non-ASCII character "**É**" is being output to 2 bytes means that it's been translated using UTF (while the page in which you are displaying it, very likely, has an ISO-8859-X character set encoding): to prevent this, you may change your instruction:

```
$shipping_street1 = (string) $order->{'shipping-address'}->address1;
```

to:

```
$shipping_street1 = 
    utf8_decode( (string) $order->{'shipping-address'}->address1);
```

(manual here: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)